# Get "Address" and "lives in" fields of facebook user by using C# SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

How can I get "Address" and "lives in" fields of a specific user by using C# SDK.
Lets say that he expose this information in his public profile information

thanks

Comment: please do some research on your own before asking (google, facebook docs, testing, ...)

Comment: I didn't find, you don't need to comment if you don't want to help....

Comment: you got 3 close votes already, i just explained why so you can improve. that IS help, actually ;) - but whatever, i am in a good mood so i will answer. ALWAYS use the facebook docs, they are very good nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Facebook docs for information and example code about users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

"lives in" would be the "location" field, you need the `user_location` permission for that. I don´t think you can get the exact address with the API. After authorizing the user with the correct permission, the location will show up in the `/me` endpoint.

Btw, it does not matter if it´s set to public or not. Not everything that is public can be accessed with the API.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) I used the Graph API Explorer on my own profile.
me/location and it's not working, so I thought there is another way to do that.

Comment: of course it´s not working. /me is the endpoint, as i wrote in my answer. it includes the name of the user, his app scoped id and the location if you authorized correctly.